# How to use Markdown and Handlebars together?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, markdown

We are using NodeJS + Express + Handlebars and it works just fine. Now we wont to use Markdown for our documentation. I looked for several days to find something I can use, and the best choice right now is mix of those packages

https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked-engine

and than register new app engine

```
app.engine('md', require('marked-engine').renderFile);
```

The main problem is that I can't use my handlebar layouts with this, so it would be great if there is another approach which would allow me to render Markdown inside handlebar layouts. And I would like to achieve that without Asemblio, Grunt or anything similar if it is possible.

Thank you in advance,

Jovan

Answer (score 0):

This is a tipical use case for a filter in template engines like handlebars. So a fast google search for filters in handlebars lead me to [**this**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars.filter) npm package. And a quick look to the docs show this

```
{{filter "## Hello *World*!" "markdown"}}   → «<h2>Hello <em>World</em>!</h2>»
```

So maybe this is exactly what you are looking for, in case that this won't work, you should still look for filters, thats the way to go for your problem. 
PS: I haven't tested this particular package

Comment: Thank you for your help Yerko! Now I have a problem to figure out how to make express-handlebars works with Filter. I hope I will figure it out soon.